# How to smoothly zoom into GeoGraphics without label flicker?

Tags: geographics, geography, dynamic

I would like to animate zooming into maps in a *smooth fashion* while showing labels - but without them flickering or jumping:

```
Manipulate[
 GeoGraphics[GeoRange -> Quantity[m, "Miles"], 
  GeoCenter -> 
   Entity["City", {"Orlando", "Florida", "UnitedStates"}]], {m, 8, 
  9, .01}]
```

[image]

As you can see, the labels show discontinuous jumps, **is there a way to avoid this**? Here's an example (from Apple Maps) that show the desired behavior, by smoothly animating the labels in and out of view during zoom:

[image]

In the comments @jose pointed out that the follwoing looks good without the labels, but as I clarified above, I need it *with labels* showing:

```
e = Entity["City", {"CapeCanaveral", "Florida", "UnitedStates"}];
Manipulate[
 GraphicsRow[{GeoGraphics[GeoRange -> Quantity[m^2, "Miles"], 
    GeoCenter -> e,
    {GeoBackground -> "StreetMapNoLabels"}
    ], GeoImage[GeoRange -> Quantity[m^2, "Miles"], GeoCenter -> e
    ]}, ImageSize -> 800], {m, .2, 20, .01}, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

**Original question/motivation:**

I was reading this [article](https://arstechnica.com/science/2020/01/spacex-set-for-critical-test-of-launch-escape-system-on-saturday/) about the SpaceX launch and wanted to recreate the smooth map zoom:

[image]

Also, it doesn't know where the Kennedy Space Center is (what to do when that happens?):

[image]

Comment: One thing their map doesn’t have (from this gif) are the intricate details of street level labels & such—it just uses silhouette/profiles of the land masses, no details. Seemingly you’d need to have to have the map rendered at the closest zoom’s level of detail, & then zoom in with that, to prevent the jittering of the updated details. As for labeling I would think you put weights to the more valuable labels & then scale them according to your window size for visibility. Then a higher valued label can make room for low values at closer zoom levels.

Comment: I would suggest to try with maps with option GeoBackground->"StreetMapNoLabels", or with the pair {GeoBackground->"Satellite", GeoServer->"DigitalGlobe"}. In both cases you will get results with no labels. Also, note the entity Entity["City", {"CapeCanaveral", "Florida", "UnitedStates"}].

Comment: @jose Thanks, I updated the question. If the natural language parse can't resolve a location, what is the smartest thing to do in general?

Comment: This is tricky basically because of how tileservers work - they are rasterized images at different zoom levels, so there is a switch between level-of-detail at different zoom levels. They are not typically vectorized in the way that apple maps etc is, so in my opinion this is a pretty hard thing to solve without turning to specialized GIS software like QGIS (I say this speaking from experience having built my own maps and tileset from scratch). One possible way _might be_ to use a no-labels tileserver and then re-add the labels you want on top using GeoMarker and so on.

Comment: @CATrevillian I updated the question to show desired label behavior